# iptables u32 basic filter not working

Tags: iptables

Trying to perform a simple match with the u32 module in `iptables` but failing, any hints would be appreciated.

I need to catch UDP packets that have a fixed header size (20+8) containing the value 02 at the beginning of the payload, in `tcpdump` I do the following both of which work just fine on the same box where `iptables` is running:

```
ip[28:1] = 0x02
udp[8:1] = 0x02
```

In `iptables` I tried the following options but none of them work, what am I missing?

```
-m u32 --u32 "28&0xFF000000=0x02"
-m u32 --u32 "0>>22&0x3C@8&0xFF000000=0x02"
```